# Missing ServiceContainer in UWP

Tags: c#, class, uwp, portable-class-library

I'm converting an app in UWP and I can't find the `System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer` class. The code to translate is:

```
if (serviceProvider == null)
{           
    ServiceContainer container = new ServiceContainer();
    container.AddService(typeof(MyInterface), this);
    serviceProvider = container;
}
return serviceProvider;
```

Is there a similar functionality or a workaround?

Comment: What is the original type of the app? wpf?

Comment: @NuwanKarunarathna Yes, it is WPF.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/Opiumtm/IpatovUWP/blob/d6b2ce014b39a363e3510b232d71e2265e702ba9/IpatovUWP/Ipatov.ServiceLocator/Core/ServiceContainer.cs but i'm not sure if it works, i've not tested it. I opted for a different software architecture.

Comment: That did not get added until .net core 2, so you would have to adjust versions in your project at a minimum.

Here is the version info when you pull it up in VS2017:
microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.5\ref\uap10.0.15138